# Can I apply R standard deviation across rows without `apply()` function?

Tags: r, purrr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4), col3 = c(9, 9))
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#    col1  col2  col3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5     6     9
# 2     2     4     9

df %>% mutate(col4 = apply(.[, c(1, 3)], 1, sum))
df %>% mutate(col4 = rowSums(.[c(1, 3)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

Lately R's `apply()` function has been trouble for me. For the time being I'm going to minimize it's use and use alternatives. @akrun educated me that I could use `rowSums()` instead of `apply()` as shown above, as an example.

But is there a way to apply, say, standard deviation across columns, like I do below. Obviously my `imaginary::rowSd` function is not going to work. It's made up.

```
df %>% mutate(col4 = apply(.[, c(1, 3)], 1, sd))
df %>% mutate(col4 = imaginary::rowSd(.[c(1, 3)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

What is an approach that would work, without using `apply()`? I'm thinking purrr although I've little knowledge on this package and the `map()` functions. Maybe there's an even easier/elegant solution.

---

[EDIT] I should've mentioned I can't use column names because the names often change in the database I pull my info from. I can only use column numbers, because relative column position doesn't change in the database I pull data from.

Comment: You can use `rowSds` from `matrixStats` after converting to a matrix `df %>% mutate(col4 = rowSds(as.matrix(.[c(1, 3)])))`

Comment: Is that package `imaginary` from `github` as I couldn't install from `CRAN`

Comment: There is really no good reason that you can't use `apply` here.

Comment: @akrun I think the package `imaginary` is just that: imaginary. As in the OP is using it as an example of where they would get the function from that they're imagining could exist

Comment: just use mutate_if `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric,list(std.dev = sd), na.rm = TRUE). You can also supply your own functions, see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html

Comment: @infominer  The OP asked for rowwise sd and not column wise

Comment: @akrun, my bad. Use rowwise `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(std.dev = sd(c(col1,col2,col3),na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @infominer  no problem. But, the OP's ask is that he doesn't know the column names (based on previous questions posted by him)

Comment: @akrun, You can't expect me or anyone to go down the rabbit hole of seeing his previous questions and thenansweing! I'm only responding to what's posted in this question. apply works fine and so would rowwise, unless there's other non-numerical columns in OP's data.frame. Yes your solution works! and I guess OP's satisfied. so will leave it at that

Comment: @infominer  I don't expect you or anybody to do that.  I was just saying based on his previous 2-3 questions.  Having said that current question asks `even easier/elegant solution`.  So, if there are 10 columns, it would be difficult to do `c(..)`

Comment: Yeah. I should've mentioned in the post I can't use actual column names, only column numbers. I'll edit it now but it's already been marked duplicate so may be too late. It looks like I have to use `purr::map()` and just read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is `rowSds` from `matrixStats`, but it works only on a `matrix`, so convert the subset of dataset to `matrix` and apply `rowSds`

```
library(matrixStats)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(col4 = rowSds(as.matrix(.[c(1, 3)]))) 
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9  2.83
#2     2     4     9  4.95
```